# Modify WooCommerce REST API product image upload

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I have to create and update products via WooCommerce REST API, without image uploads to media library (only the image source is need to be stored, because they are hosted on another server).

In the [`wc-rest-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-rest-functions.php) there are 2 functions I want to override:

- `wc_rest_upload_image_from_url` (line 67) and
- `wc_rest_set_uploaded_image_as_attachment` (line 130)

which are called from the [`WC_REST_Products_Controller`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-rest-products-controller.php) class from the `set_product_images` (line 228) method.

I have searched for actions or filters to achieve the desired result with no luck.

Is there any way to modify the functionality of image upload without edit the core WooCommerce files (somehow redeclare the functions, or replace the controller class with a custom one)?